# How to filter datagridview using datetime picker C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

```
private void dateTimePicker2_KeyUp_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    sc.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = sc.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from grn1 where date like ('" + dateTimePicker2.Text + "%')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    sc.Close();
}
```

This is my code. While trying with this code it hide all the data from gridview. I don't no what is the way to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- use [SqlParameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to prevent [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
- use a correct SQL syntax to query DateTime field
- use [DateTimePicker.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

So modify your code in:

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from grn1 where date = @YourDate";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@YourDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
```

Comment: First i tried with your code, Its not worked. Then I tried Changing the to "SqlDbType.Date" its working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub DataGridViewTest_DefaultValuesNeeded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewTest.DefaultValuesNeeded
        With e.Row
            .Cells("Fieldname").Value = Format(txtDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
        End With
    End Sub

Try this.  :)